# Unable to open stream (fopen) php

Tags: php, fopen

What is my mistake?

```
$url = 'http://sc-stream1.dancefm.net/;';

if (!$fp = fopen($url, 'r')) {
    trigger_error("Error URL ($url)", E_USER_ERROR);
}
```

works:

```
$url = 'http://sc-stream1.dancefm.net/';
```

error:

```
$url = 'http://sc-stream1.dancefm.net/;';
```

Comment: Why is there a semi-colon in the url?

Comment: This looks like an Icecast server (the response is `ICY 200 OK`). Related question : http://stackoverflow.com/a/18642555/211840

Comment: because this audio stream